# When did Kamsa defeat the Devas?

Tags: mahabharata, indra, vishnu-purana, devatas

I was going through the Vishnu Puran and came across the following description in [Book V, Chapter IV](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp121.htm):

*KANSA, much troubled in mind, summoned all his principal Asuras, Pralamba, Keśin, and the rest, and said to them, "O valiant chiefs, Pralamba, Keśin, Dhenuka, Pútaná, Arisht́a, and all the rest of you, hear my words. The vile and contemptible denizens of heaven are assiduously plotting against my life, for they dread my prowess: but, heroes, I hold them of no account. **What can the impotent Indra, or the ascetic Hara, perform? or what can Hari accomplish, except the murder of his foes by fraud? What have we to fear from the Ádityas, the Vasus, the Agnis, or any others of the immortals, who have all been vanquished by my resistless arms? Have I not seen the king of the gods, when he had ventured into the conflict, quickly retreat from the field, receiving my shafts upon his back, not bravely upon his breast?** When in resentment he withheld the fertilizing showers from my kingdom, did not my arrows compel the clouds to part with their waters, as much as were required? Are not all the monarchs of the earth in terror of my prowess, and subject to my orders, save only Jarásandha my sire?*

I want to know if there are more details given about this encounter between Kamsa and the Devas in any other scripture especially with Indra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Garga Samhita** describes the battle between Kamsa and the Devas in its [First Canto, Chapter 7](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.7:_Description_of_the_Conquest_of_All_Directions).

According to this narration, after Kamsa had acquired the friendship of all the asuras such as Narakasura, Bana, Baka, Agha, Keshi, Pralamba, et al, he led them on a conquest of Svargaloka.

> Text 27
>
> canura-mushtikarishta- shala-toshala-keshibhih pralambena bakenapi dvividena samavritah
> trinavartagha-kutaish ca bhauma-banakhya-shambaraih vyoma-dhenuka-vatsaish ca rurudhe so 'maravatim
>
> Aided by Canura, Mushtika, Arishta, Shala, Toshala, Keshi, Pralamba,
> Baka, Dvivida, Trinavarta, Agha, Kuta, Narakasura, Bana, Shambara,
> Vyoma, Dhenuka, and Vatsa, he besieged the city of Aamaravati.
>
> Text 29
>
> kamsadin agatan drittva shakro devadhipah svarat sarvair deva-ganaih
> sardham yoddhum kruddho viniryayau
>
> Seeing the demons headed by Kamsa had come, Indra, the sovereign king
> of the demigods became angry and, accompanied by a great host of
> demigods, went to fight with them.

The battle is described in great detail, followed by the surrender and fleeing of the devas, in concurrence with the Vishnu Purana quotation of Kamsa.

> Text 52
>
> grihitva vaishnavam capam sajjam kritvatha daitya-rat devan vidravayam
> asa banaughaish ca dhanuh-svanaih
>
> Taking the bow of Lord Vishnu and stringing it, **with a flood of arrows
> accompanied by the twanging sound of the bow, the demon-king Kamsa
> made the demigods flee.**
>
> Text 53
>
> tatah suras tena nihanyamana vidudruvur dina-dhiyo disham te kecid
> rane mukta-shikha babhuvur bhitah sma ittham yudhi vadinas te
>
> As Kamsa was attacking and killing them, **the dispirited demigods fled
> in all directions.** Some, their helmets lost, screamed in terror.
>
> Text 54
>
> kecit tatha pranjalayo 'ti-dina-vat sannyasta-shastra yudhi
> mukta-kacchakah sthatum rane kamsa-nri-deva-sammukhe gatepsitah kecid
> ativa-vihvalah
>
> Some, dropping their weapons and armor, humbly surrendered with folded
> hands. **Others, very troubled, had lost all desire to stand before King
> Kamsa.**

Though not explicitly named, one can understand that Indra being the chief of the devas too would have similarly fled the battle along with the rest of the army, and this would tally with the fact that the devas themselves accompany Bhudevi to Shvetadvipa to request Bhagavan's protection, since they too would have been subject to the torture of the asuras, here led by Kamsa.

This fact is further confirmed in the **Bhagavata Purana**, in the [Tenth Canto, Chapter Four](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/4/), which is the equivalent of the Vishnu Purana Chapter (5.4) quoted in the question. Here the various asuras recount the above battle of Kamsa with the devas, and describe nearly the same account.

> Text 32: The demigods always fear the sound of your bowstring. They
> are constantly in anxiety, afraid of fighting. Therefore, what can
> they do by their endeavors to harm you?
>
> Text 33: **While being pierced
> by your arrows, which you discharged on all sides, some of them, who
> were injured by the multitude of arrows but who desired to live, fled
> the battlefield, intent on escaping.**
>
> Text 34: Defeated and bereft of
> all weapons, **some of the demigods gave up fighting and praised you
> with folded hands**, and some of them, appearing before you with
> loosened garments and hair, said, “O lord, we are very much afraid of
> you.”
>
> Text 35: When the demigods are bereft of their chariots, when
> they forget how to use weapons, when they are fearful or attached to
> something other than fighting, or when their bows are broken and they
> have thus lost the ability to fight, Your Majesty does not kill them.

Thus, the battle between Kamsa and the devas is described primarily in the above two texts in support of the description of Vishnu Purana, and may have been one of the final triggers for the advent of Lord Krsna's Avatara.

Comment: Thant's great thanks for sharing both the references!